# How to draw rectange inside fix size rectange using percentage unit in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I can draw such inner rectange inside fixed size rectange using absolute unit like in this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test div dimension</title>
    <style>
        #main {
            width: 640px;
            height: 360px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #content {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #slide {
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: calc(640*0.75px);
            height: calc(360*0.75px);
            float: right;
        }

        #camera {
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: calc(640 * 0.25px);
            height: calc(360 * 0.25px);
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="slide">
                Rectange 1
            </div>
            
            <div id="camera">
                Rectange 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I use percentage(`%`) based unit instead of `px` to create such inner rectangles to avoid calculation like `calc(640*0.75px)`?

I tried this but did not work

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test div dimension</title>
    <style>
        #main {
            width: 640px;
            height: 360px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #content {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #slide {
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 75%;
            height: 75%;
            float: right;
        }

        #camera {
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 25%;
            height: 25%;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="slide">
                Rectange 1
            </div>

            <div id="camera">
                Rectange 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the slide and camera's width and height in percentages but that percentage will be of the parent which is the content div. But the content width has a height of 0 because you haven't set it. So change content's style to this:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and add percentages to camera and slide like this:

```
#slide {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    float: right;
}

#camera {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the topmost div height in terms of viewport height like this: `100vh`, and then make the inner div's take height in %. The snippet is given below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test div dimension</title>
    <style>
        #main {
            width: 640px;
            height: 100vh;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #slide {
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 50% !important;
            height: 50%;
            float: right;
        }

        #camera {
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 50% !important;
            height: 50%;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="slide">
                Rectange 1
            </div>
            
            <div id="camera">
                Rectange 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```